# How to open the .docx file or .xls using react-native-file-viewer?

Tags: react-native

I want to know how to open the .docx file or .xls file using  react native file viewer in android.I am using RNFetchblob todownload the file.PDF and Image  files are getting opened.While am trying to open .docx file or .xls file using  react native file viewer am getting the error like no app is found to open this mime type

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a pdf viewer in your emulator or mobile.
Then you can open the docs. See [Reference](https://github.com/vinzscam/react-native-file-viewer/issues/23#issuecomment-435027532)